# Balanced or Unbalanced dataset for the following problem?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

Problem: Impact of weather severity index on # of days delayed for a shipment sample.

X, weather severity index = 1-10, 10 being the most severe (e.g. Hurricane)

y, # of days delayed = (Actual delivery days) - (Expected delivery days)

Roughly 5% of the sample is delayed (actual > expected), so 95% is on-time. However, I'm NOT looking for a binary outcome. Additionally, 95% of y-values are between 0-5 days delayed.

Q: Do I need to balance the sample set (delayed vs. on-time) before doing any type of analysis?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with this data?

Comment: 1st step - basic pearson correlation between X & y. Version 1 - determine what X value (if any) causes a delay with est # of days delayed.